# Ruby Regex match a newline followed by anything but (3 uppercase characters followed by a pipe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, sublimetext

(Hopefully) simple regex question here. I'm looking to match 1 or more newlines that aren't followed by a certain pattern of three uppercase characters and a pipe (`|`), and remove them.

For an example,I'm looking to turn this:

```
foo bar foo bar.



Normal

0

false

false

false



EN-US

JA


X-NONE




foo bar foo bar




|||||HH
OBX|156|TX|foo bar|||N
OBX|157|TX|foo bar
```

Into this:

```
foo bar foo bar. Normal  0 false  false false  EN-US JA  X-NONE|||||HH
OBX|156|TX|foo bar|||N
OBX|157|TX|foo bar
```

I have the regex that works great in Sublime here:

```
(\n+)(?!MSH|PID|NTE|PV1|RXO|ORC|DG1|OBR|OBX).*
```

But In ruby, it's not getting rid of the newlines. Is there anything I'm missing when converting the sublime regex into regex for rails?

```
@r.force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub("\r\n","\r").gsub("(\r+)(?!MSH|PID|NTE|PV1|RXO|ORC|DG1|OBR|OBX)(.*)"," $2")
```

Comment: Have you tried expressing your regular expression as a regexp and not a string? That is: `gsub(/(\r+).../)` and not `gsub("(\r+)...")`

Comment: You can simplify the regex like: `\n+(?!([A-Z]{3}).*)`.

Comment: I don't understand why the first line of your desired output is not `foo bar foo bar.Normal0falsefalsefalseEN-USJAX-NONEfoo bar foo bar|||||HH`. That is,  why are the groups of newlines converted to spaces (and why there is one space sometimes and two spaces at other times) and what happened to the second `"foo bar foo bar"`?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, I rushed a little making this example, essentially I just wanted groups of one or more newlines converted to one space. @archana and @tadman got it though with using `//` instead of a string.

Comment: You should edit to correct the desired output, as your question, though answered, may be read by many in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = <<-MULTI
foo bar foo bar.



Normal

0

false

false

false



EN-US

JA


X-NONE




foo bar foo bar




|||||HH
OBX|156|TX|foo bar|||N
OBX|157|TX|foo bar
MULTI

str.gsub(/(\n+)(?!MSH|PID|NTE|PV1|RXO|ORC|DG1|OBR|OBX).*/,'')

# It gives your desired result
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, but can you explain why yours worked over mine? Does `/` behave differently from quotes?

Comment: Your regex is a pattern. Anything within quotes is a string and not a pattern. Please read here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub. From this doc "The pattern is typically a Regexp; if given as a String, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. '\\d' will match a backlash followed by ‘d’, instead of a digit."

Comment: If `str = "abc\nOSBxyz"` and `r = /(\n+)(?!MSH|PID|NTE|PV1|RXO|ORC|DG1|OBR|OBX).*/`, `str.gsub(r,'') #=> "abc"`, but it should return `"abcOSBxyz"` as `"OSB"` is not followed by a pipe. If `str = "abc\nOSB|xyz"`, `str.gsub(r,'') #=> "abc"`, but in that case it should return  `str`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to handle the lines individually, multi-line regex can be quite confusing for many people.

.each_line or .lines both return the individual lines.

.grep will match an array against a regular expression or string based pattern.

.join will take the individual lines and return a single multiline string from the results.

```
str.each_line
   .grep( /^[A-Z]{3,3}\|.+/ )
   .join( '' )
```

As far as the regex, lets break that down too, now that we are only dealing with things line by line:

```
^      - Starting at the beginning of the line.
[A-Z]  - Only match the range of chars from 'A' to 'Z' ( all cap chars ).
{3, 3} - Match only 3 chars, no more, no less.
\|     - Followed by a '|' char.
.+     - Followed by 1+ chars of anything.
```

Comment: There's a problem: `"abc".each_line.grep( /^[A-Z]{3,3}\|.+/ ).join( '' ) #=> ""`. Two small things: `{3,3}` is the same as `{3}` and `join('')` is the same as `join`.

Comment: I prefer being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is your string,

```
r = /
    \n+                        # match one or more newlines
    (?!                        # start a negative lookahead
      #{Regexp.union(keepers)} # match one of keepers
      \|                       # match pipe--escape required
    )                          # close negative lookahead 
    /x                         # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /
      \n+
      (?!
        (?-mix:MSH|PID|NTE|PV1|RXO|ORC|DG1|OBR|OBX)
        \|
      )
      /x 

keepers = %w[ MSH PID NTE PV1 RXO ORC DG1 OBR OBX ]
  #=> ["MSH", "PID", "NTE", "PV1", "RXO", "ORC", "DG1", "OBR", "OBX"] 

puts str.gsub(r, "")
  # foo bar foo bar.Normal0falsefalsefalseEN-USJAX-NONEfoo bar foo bar|||||HH
  # OBX|156|TX|foo bar|||N
  # OBX|157|TX|foo bar
```